# Why doesn't TCusomWinSocket.ReceiveBuf ever return 0?

Tags: delphi, sockets

When it comes to sockets, TClientSocket and TServerSockets are my favourite because of their simple usage.

My task is very simple. I need to send a file (RAW) through these 2 components, so I have 2 routines like the ones below:

```
procedure csRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
   MSCli : TMemoryStream;
   cnt   : Integer;
   buf   : array [0..1023] of byte;
begin
    MSCli := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
    repeat
      cnt := Socket.ReceiveBuf(buf[0], 1024); //This loop repeats endlesly
      MSCli.Write(buf[0], cnt)
    until cnt = 0;
    finally
    MSCli.SaveToFile('somefile.dmp');
    MSCli.Free;
    end;
end;
```

And of course the sender :

```
  //...some code
    MSSErv.LoadFromFile('some file');
    MSServ.Position := 0;
    Socket.SendStream(MSServ);
  end;
```

The loop in the reader is repeating endelessly and I don't know why. What could be the source of the problem?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken you should use 'until cnt < 1', I can't see right now what "ReceiveBuf" returns...

Comment: Agreed. ReceiveBuf might return a -1 (SOCKET_ERROR)

Comment: `ReceiveBuf()` returns 0 only when `Count=-1` and no data is available (used by `ReceiveLength()` internally), or when the socket is disconnected. `ReceiveBuf()` returns -1 if the socket reports an `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error on a non-blocking socket, or a real socket error occurs and an assigned `OnError` event handler sets `ErrorCode := 0`.  Otherwise, `ReceiveBuf()` will raise an `ESocketError` exception instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

`SendStream()` is not a particularly good choice to use - EVER.  It is intended to send the entire `TStream` and then free it when finished.  However, if the socket is set to non-blocking mode and the socket blocks during sending, `SendStream()` exits immediately and DOES NOT free the `TStream`.  You have to call `SendStream()` again to continue sending the `TStream` from where `SendStream()` left off.  But there are other conditions that can cause `SendStream()` to exit AND free the `TStream`, and you don't really know when it did or did not free the `TStream`, so it becomes very dangerous to try to call `SendStream()` again with the same `TStream` object.  A much safer approach is to avoid `SendStream()` at all costs and call `SendBuf()` directly in your own loop instead.

With that said, `SendStream()` does not inform the receiver how many bytes will be sent, so the receiver does not know when to stop reading (unless you close the connection after sending the `TStream`).  A better choice is to send the intended byte count before then sending the `TStream` data.  That way, the receiver can read the byte count first, then stop reading when the specified number of bytes have been received.  For example:

```
procedure ReadRawFromSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; Buffer: Pointer; BufSize: Integer);
var 
  buf: PByte; 
  cnt: Integer; 
begin 
  buf := PByte(Buffer); 
  while BufSize > 0 do
  begin 
    cnt := Socket.ReceiveBuf(buf^, BufSize);
    if cnt < 1 then begin
      if (cnt = -1) and (WSAGetLastError() = WSAEWOULDBLOCK) then
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        Continue;
      end;
      Abort;
    end;
    Inc(buf, cnt);
    Dec(BufSize, cnt);
  end; 
end;

function ReadInt64FromSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket): Int64;
begin
  ReadRawFromSocket(Socket, @Result, SizeOf(Int64));
end;

procedure ReadMemStreamFromSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket: Stream: TMemoryStream);
var
  cnt: Int64; 
begin
  cnt := ReadInt64FromSocket(Socket);
  if cnt > 0 then
  begin
    Stream.Size := cnt; 
    ReadRawFromSocket(Socket, Stream.Memory, cnt);
  end; 
end;

procedure csRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket); 
var 
  MSCli : TMemoryStream; 
begin 
  MSCli := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try 
    ReadMemStreamFromSocket(Socket, MSCli);
    MSCli.SaveToFile('somefile.dmp'); 
  finally
    MSCli.Free; 
  end; 
end; 

procedure SendRawToSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; Buffer: Pointer; BufSize: Integer);
var 
  buf: PByte; 
  cnt: Integer; 
begin 
  buf := PByte(Buffer); 
  while BufSize > 0 do
  begin 
    cnt := Socket.SendBuf(buf^, BufSize);
    if cnt < 1 then begin
      if (cnt = -1) and (WSAGetLastError() = WSAEWOULDBLOCK) then
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        Continue;
      end;
      Abort;
    end;
    Inc(buf, cnt);
    Dec(BufSize, cnt);
  end; 
end;

procedure SendInt64ToSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket; Value: Int64);
begin
  SendRawToSocket(Socket, @Value, SizeOf(Int64));
end;

procedure SendMemStreamToSocket(Socket: TCustomWinSocket: Stream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  SendInt64FromSocket(Socket, Stream.Size);
  SendRawToSocket(Socket, Stream.Memory, Stream.Size);
end;

begin
  ...
  MSSErv.LoadFromFile('some file'); 
  MSServ.Position := 0; 
  SendMemStreamToSocket(Socket, MSServ);
  ...
end;
```